# Solving the Riccati equation $y' = x + y/x + y^2/x.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve

$$y' = x + \frac {y}{x} + \frac {y^2}{x}.$$

First, I find that $y = x \tan \left( x \right)$ is a particular solution. Then I have a problem about the homogeneous solution. Really, I don't know. Any idea, please?

Comment: Maybe [conversion to a second order linear equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation#Conversion_to_a_second_order_linear_equation) will be fruitful.

Comment: Make a substitution $y = u+x\tan(x)$. For $u$ you will get Bernoulli's equation, which can be integrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: maybe the subsitution ${t = \frac{y}{x}}$ will help.

Comment: all hail lord pointy nose and his brilliant insights